# c# Retrieving value in controller from dynamically created check boxes in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

I have the following code in my view:

```
@foreach (var x in model)
{
     <input type="checkbox" name="@x.name" /> @x.name
}
```

That loop will create about 10 check boxes with each of them having a unique name generated during the runtime. The whole point of this is to make this dynamic without me having to type the values of each name. So when I am trying to check in my controller if each of these check boxes are checked or not, how do I do it? Normally, I would pass a parameter to my controller

`public ActionResult MyController(string/bool checkboxName)`

and this would work fine if I had one checkbox. However, passing 10 parameters for each check box in the controller sounds insane! What if I add more to `x in model` later so that I have 20 check boxes?

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do. You checkboxes do not even have a value attribute (and you could never have used `bool checkboxName` to bind if you had one checkbox) What do you actually want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you are creating the checkboxes, add them to an ICollection and then iterate over that collection looking for CheckBox.Checked.

I'm certain there is a helper function for that in MVC but I'm traveling and don't quite remember it. Something like this should work, adapt as needed.

Note: This assumes they are all on the same page.

```
@foreach (var control in this.Controls) 
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)control).Checked)
                {
                    //record as you need
                }                                                                                
            }
        }
```

Comment: a demo would be very helpful :)

Comment: not quite sure how this piece of code works, but please let me know about the MVC helper function for this if you figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the ways to do this, which might not be ideal but can still work is to use the FormCollection in the MVC framework since you are using a loop, you can loop the elements in your action 
/// your view side

```
@foreach (var x in model)
{
     <input type="checkbox" name="@x.name" /> @x.name
}
```

///The action side

```
public ActionResult MyController(FormCollection collection, YourModel model)
{

   foreach (var x in model)
   {
      bool IsThisCheked= Convert.ToBoolean(collection[x.name].ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: How/Why is the model passed as a parameter to retrieve value from view to controller? It stays null and no value is getting passed in my case.

Comment: you do not need to pass model as parameter it was just as example

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the whole list of checkboxes to the post controller and then iterate through them like

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(List<Requirements> requirements)
    {
     foreach (var item in requirements)
        {

          if (item.IsSelected == true)
          {
            //perform some operation
          }
        }
```

List is the list that I passed from view to controller on submitting the form
Now coming to view it can be something like this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Requirements.Count; i++)
        {
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Requirements[i].RId)
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Requirements[i].IsSelected, new { id = "requirements_" + i, @class = "divider" })
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Requirements[i].RName)             
        }
```

RId,RName,IsSelected(someproperty to store boolean) are my model properties related to checkboxlist